# trying to find cube via this code in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, ksh

I have written this code to find cube of the number which I am passing while executing this script like:
./my_script.sh 6

The code is working fine till 6 but after 6 it start producing unexpected results. For 7 it should give me cubeof(7) which is 343 but this code gives me 87 for that.

```
cube () {
        return `expr "$1" \* "$1" \* "$1" `;
}

cube $1;
echo $?;
```

Some more test cases:

For 8 expected answer should be 512 but it gives 0
same as 9 it gives 217 as results

Comment: `expr` is an artifact of the 1970s. Shell-builtin math has been part of the POSIX sh standard since 1992; use it.

Comment: That said, the big issue is that `return` is only for exit status, and exit status is a subset of a 16-bit value. It can't be used for arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: Just emit the result on stdout, exactly like expr does, instead of using return. So `cube() { echo "$(( $1 * $1 * $1 ))"; }`, or to do it the inefficient old-school way, `cube() { expr "$1" "*" "$1" "*" "$1"; }` -- no `return`s needed.

Comment: But I also want to store the result in a variable to use it somewhere else in the program

Comment: `result=$(cube 8)`, then.

Comment: BTW, using `$(...)` instead of backticks is another thing that's been standardized since the POSIX.2 standard came out in '92; see also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Adding to the comment by Charles Duffy: ... and since the upper half of the 16 bit value communicated by `return` usually undergoes a specific interpretation, you can safely use only the lower half, 8 bit. Even there, it is discouraged to use the topmost bit, which leaves you with 7 bit only; and since 126 and 127 have specific meaning too, you better stick to numbers in the range from 0 to 125. See [here](https://linuxconfig.org/list-of-exit-codes-on-linux). Not much arithmetic can be done in this numeric range.